# mobile automation nodejs appium aws

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, mocha.js, appium

Need to automate mobile application on AWS. I am using nodejs with mocha framework currently. I have creates some test cases, those needs to be run on android and ios emulators/simulators.

Anyone having any idea on this? How to integrate all these(nodejs, appium)?

If so, kindly explain.

Till now i know, AWS device farm can be use, but there is no provision for javascript, it only allows to work on java.

Answer (score 0):

Using AWS device farm, the only way to run JavaScript appium tests currently is to use the private device offering. However this would require more up front cost.

If we need the JavaScript appium client, I think sauce labs has an offering that supports it but I have not used it before.
https://wiki.saucelabs.com/display/DOCS/Node.js+Example+Script+for+Android+Mobile+Application+Tests?desktop=true&macroName=view-git-file

Hope that helps

James